# Making web browser without features in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, web

I'm very new to iOS web programming so I need help.

I want make an app which shows a map with stores (I actually made it with MapKit) on 1 tab of Tab Bar Controller. On 2-4 I want provide some info (sales, news, new arrivals, etc). I think I could make 3 web browsers without any features, such as: search, url, back and forward buttons. I'll load prepared URLs and show info without downloading it.

My question is: can you make a web browser in such way? If so, tell me please how or give a link.

Comment: why do you think it should not work?

Answer (score 2):

[UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you are looking for. You can create viewControllers with webViews and add them to the tabBarController to get what you want.